# Making a Scene more Realistic

Tags: rendering, texturing, shaders

I just finished modeling a lighthouse scene. My goal was to make the scene realistic, however the result turned out to be very artificial. I tried to add a normal to the material of the lighthouse, however it was causing issues with it.  I would greatly appreciate any advice on how to make the scene look more realistic.

Thanks

P.S.
I included 2 images, one is my render and the other one is my inspiration image.

[image: My Render]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. Take more time to study materials. Water is darker and has a gradient affected by the depth as it gets closer to the coast. (try to make tiling less obvious, combine different bumps or use smth procedural). The roughness from the sand/ ground is too shiny. The lighthouse has kind off poor shading it needs roughneess variation to push its quality.
2. Study as if you were painting check how values work in the pictures and try to match them in your materials. Use HDRI and photometric color
3. Your shapes are too general there is no depth in terms on diferent scale, try not to skip details go from big shapes to the tiniest this can help you get a scale sensation and realism
4. Keep working on it, compare more photos, close ups from similar materials, study a lot. You can do this, build patience :)

Comment: btw check tutorials about shading, and set Normal map with its normalmap node and set to non color

Comment: In addition the points above, check out some of the helpful tips in this article: https://blog.usejournal.com/5-reasons-why-your-3d-renders-look-fake-5d20d8118023